# Print the distance result on same page without redirecting to other page during page loading

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

I have implemented below code to print the distance from current location and given location.

As per current situation, when the page is getting loaded then one hyperlink is being generated, when I click on that URL then it redirects to me on different page and shows the distance results.

Is there any way to print the results directly on same page on loading time without clicking on any link?

```
<html>
<body onLoad="javascript:showlocation()">
<p id="demo"></p>


<script>
function showlocation()
{
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(callback);
}

function callback(position) 
{
    var str = "Free Web Building Tutorials!";
    var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins="+position.coords.latitude+","+position.coords.longitude+"&destinations=london&mode=transit&transit_mode=train&key=AIzaSyCeBdq7rr-R7w7vZCXscLWgEDb3oO9CUhw";
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = str.link(url);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could try using ajax took load the link target and dump the response html into your DOM; it should work, only if Google maps api CORS configuration allows ajax calls from any origin.  Failing that, you could use an iframe with the source the same as the link you're creating.

Comment: Thanks Dan for your response.. I was thinking to use iframe but I am not able to understand how will I return the URL from showlocation function.. because showlocation function is calling callback function. Could you please help me out to return the URL from showlocation function?

Comment: Why not just insert into the DOM the same way you're doing the anchor?  Which is to say, update the DOM from the callback!

Comment: Dan.. I didn't get you. Can u please explain?

Answer (score 1):

You should look into how Javascript can manipulate the DOM - add and remove elements, change text and html, etc.  I also recommend checking out JQuery as raw browser javascript tends to get very messy, very quickly.  Highly recommended from someone who avoids libraries when possible.

You can pretty easily set the window's location in *most* cases with

```
window.location = url; // eg, 'https://google.com'
```

For example, if I open this with a `file://` url in my browser, it works:

```
<script>
url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=-93.243956,44.909974&destinations=new%20york&mode=transit&transit_mode=train&key=AIzaSyCeBdq7rr-R7w7vZCXscLWgEDb3oO9CUhw'
function setLocation(){
  window.location = url;
}
</script>
<body onLoad='setLocation()' >
</body>
```

That should essentially have the same result of clicking a matching link. Unfortunately I couldn't get it to work in a stack overflow snippet, but I tested the content in a file locally and it redirects fine.  If it doesn't work for you, I'd recommend posting a more complete example.

If you want to leave other content on the page as well, you have a few options.   Some APIs allow calls from AJAX or iframes - others may use authentication, CORS, or some other means to disallow.

From the examples below, it's evident that Google is disallowing these requests by setting the appropriate headers ( The browser console will explain that display is blocked ).  It's not uncommon for folks like Google to protect their free APIs with mechanisms to try to stop folks from rebranding their products or abusing their offerings.  I'm sure if you look at the documentation for the API you're trying to use, it will explain how you can authenticate these requests for the user.

Below there's an example that manipulates the DOM in a few ways - with `innerHTML`, a vanilla javascript browser method, and with JQuery ($ is a synonym for the JQuery interface ) - which you'll see is far easier ( what you may not see is how hard it is to do things *without* jquery across all the relevant web browsers!  ).  If you swap out the URL you can see that the commands work when the URL response allows the browser to display them.

```js
  function showlocation()
{
   //navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(callback);
  callback( { coords: { longitude: 44.909974, latitude: -93.243956 } } );
}

             
function callback(position) 
{
    var str = "Free Web Building Tutorials!";
    var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins="+position.coords.latitude+","+position.coords.longitude+"&destinations=new%20york&mode=transit&transit_mode=train&key=AIzaSyCeBdq7rr-R7w7vZCXscLWgEDb3oO9CUhw";
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = str.link(url);
    document.getElementById("iframe").src = url;
    ajax(url);
}


function ajax(url){
  $('#ajaxres').html("Loading...");
  $.ajax({ 
     url: url, 
     success: function(result, status){
        $('#ajaxres').html( result );
                 
     },
     error: function(req, status, msg){
       $('#ajaxres').html( "Error!  Status: " + status + ", message: <code>"+msg+"</code>, Response: <pre> " + JSON.stringify(req) + "</pre>" ); 
     }
  })
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: aquamarine;
  }
code:before {
   content: "'";
  }
code:after {
    content: "'";
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<script>

  </script>
  </head>
<body onLoad="showlocation();">
<p id="demo"></p>
<p>This won't work because X-Frame-Options header of the response is SAMEORIGIN ( see browser console for errors ).  You'll just see an empty box with an ugly 90s border (but ymmv):</p>
<iframe id='iframe'></iframe>
<p>The AJAX also doesn't work because </code> the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present on the requested resource</code> ( see console )</p>
<div id='ajaxres'></div>
</body>
</html>
```